# styled-component props is not applied to css

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm passing a prop to control an opacity of text, and I can see the prop is passed, but somehow it doesn't work on CSS part. Here's the code

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'

//——*——*——*——*——*——//
const Logo = props => {
  const { hide } = props
  return (
    <StyledLogo>
      <LogoGroup>
        <NavLink to="/" className="logo">
          seungmee lee{hide}
        </NavLink>

        <HideText>
          &nbsp;is <br />
          an experience designer, <br />
          creating and visualizing new experiences
        </HideText>
      </LogoGroup>
    </StyledLogo>
  )
}

const StyledLogo = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  z-index: 999;


  & p:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  & .logo {
    font-weight: 600;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    z-index: 100;
  }
`
const LogoGroup = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 3vw;
  left: 3vw;
`

const HideText = styled.p`
  font-size: 1.2em;
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: ${props => props.hide};
`
export default Logo
```

```
import React from 'react'
// import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
// 1. Dependencies
// 2. Components
// 3. for style
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import WorksCard from '../components/WorksCard'
import Logo from '../components/Logo'
import WORKLIST from '../screens/work-list.json'
import EXPERIMENTLIST from '../screens/experiment-list.json'

// 4. Static Resources

//——*——*——*——*——*——//

const Works = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Logo hide={0.5} />
      <StyledWorks>
        .......
      </StyledWorks>
    </div>
  )
}
.....

export default Works
```

I could test if the value of 'hide' is passed by including it in text, but when I use it here >> opacity: ${props => props.hide}; it is not applied on actual css.

I'm not sure what is causing the issue. It seems like a basic question, but I couldn't figure out when I checked similar questions.

Comment: did you try this:  <HideText hide = {hide}>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send props to the tag. like,

```
<HideText hide={hide}>
   &nbsp;is <br />
   an experience designer, <br />
   creating and visualizing new experiences
</HideText>
```

FIR: props are sent via the tag

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize that!!